# Validate attribute titles exists in web-elements

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a question regarding list of web elements.
I have a method that verify if text exists in list of web elements.
I need to modify it to support attribute title, and validate if value exists.
Is their a way to change this method to support attribute title?

My method:

```
public Boolean isStringInWebElementsAttributeList(String expectedValue,List<WebElement> dropdownOptions) throws Exception {
        Boolean  isExists = dropdownOptions.stream().map(WebElement::getText).anyMatch(text -> expectedValue.equals(text));
        return isExists;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of mapping the `getText` map the element's `title` attribute.

```
public Boolean isStringInWebElementsAttributeList(String expectedValue,List<WebElement> dropdownOptions) throws Exception {
        Boolean  isExists = dropdownOptions.stream()
                            .map(el->el.getAttribute("title"))
                            .anyMatch(text -> expectedValue.equals(text));
        return isExists;
    }
```